# Lua.GetFunction Returns Null

Tags: c#, lua

I'm very new to lua this is my first program to use it at all. The code uses a Lua File to create a menu for a game I'm working on.

This line creates a button in the MainMenu screen, it sends the name of the function to call when the button is pressed.

Lua:

```
CreateButton( "mainmenu", "NewGame", "New Game", 50, 120, 150, 32)

function NewGame()
--CODE TO START NEW GAME
end
```

C#:

```
public class LuaWrapper
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        lua = new Lua();
        lua.RegisterFunction("CreateButton", this, 
           this.GetType().GetMethod("CreateButton"));

        lua.DoFile("Data/Menus/Main.lua");
    }

    public void CreateButton(string window, string functionName, string text,
         float posx, float posy, float width, float height)
    {
        ButtonControl button = new ButtonControl();
        button.Bounds = new UniRectangle(posx, posy, width, height);
        button.Text = text;
        LuaFunction f = lua.GetFunction(functionName); // <-- RETURNS NULL ?

        ButtonPressEvent pressEvent = new ButtonPressEvent(f);
        button.Pressed += new EventHandler(pressEvent.button_Pressed);

        WindowDictionary[window].Children.Add(button);
    }
}

class ButtonPressEvent
{
    LuaFunction function;

    public ButtonPress(LuaFunction function)
    {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public void button_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        function.Call();
    }
}
```

It all works fine until the button is clicked and it tries to call the associated function
It throws a Null Reference Exception on Funtion.Call(); Under the ButtonPress Class. I have used break points and found out that the problem is

```
 LuaFunction f = lua.GetFunction(functionName);
```

returns Null.

Note: I've also tried

```
LuaFunction f = lua.GetFunction("NewGame");
```

With the same results.

Thanks Reading, hope any one can help point out what I've done wrong.

Comment: In Lua, functions don't get defined if their code is invalid. Are you certain your NewGame code is correct?

Comment: Yes, and thank you, I just remembered what you posted and you solved a different problem that has occurred :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a thought and tried changing the order of the Lua File. I guess I was calling the creation of the button before The function had been read ? I'm not sure but this seems to have fixed it.

Lua:

```
function NewGame()
--CODE TO START NEW GAME
end

CreateButton( "mainmenu", "NewGame", "New Game", 50, 120, 150, 32)
```