# GetFunction returns null luainterface

Tags: c#, .net, lua, luainterface

I have this script loaded in my C# program

```
function test()
    print ("A")
end
```

but when I try to invoke it

```
LuaFunction func = lua.GetFunction("test")

func.call()
```

I get the problem that func is null.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Try out what's discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12225260/1649124)

Comment: I found the problem, it was because I did LoadString, not doString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have *loaded* the `test` script into the C# program. This is not enough. You have to *execute* the resulting chunk code so that the global `test` variable gets assigned.

Always reminder that

```
function test()
    print ("A")
end
```

is only a syntactic sugar for:

```
test = function()
    print ("A")
end
```

When Lua *loads* some code, it just compiles the source code into bytecode.The affectation `test = function() end` is only executed at runtime, not at compile time.